# Unix subversion branch commands returning errors

Tags: svn, branch

I've read through the technical manual (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.using.html) and several posts of questions and answers related to subversion branches, but I'm having trouble creating a branch to a program already committed to subversion. This is on a unix server.

The parent programs are here:

```
/au/test/csr/pgm
```

Not sure if this is necessary information, but the repository is here:

```
/au/test/csr/repo
```

I want to copy the programs to this folder and make them the main versions:

```
/au/test/csr/new/pgm
```

Attempt 1:

```
cd /au/test/csr/pgm
svn copy /au/test/csr/pgm /au/test/csr/new/pgm
```

The resulting error:

```
svn: E155007: '/au/test/csr/new/pgm' is not a working copy
```

Attempt 2:

```
cd /au/test/csr/pgm
svn copy /au/test/csr/pgm \ /au/test/csr/new/pgm
```

The resulting error:

```
svn: E200007: Cannot copy path '/au/test/csr/pgm' into its own child '/au/test/csr/pgm/ /au/test/csr/new/pgm'
```

What are the commands to make a branch of the programs in this directory /au/test/csr/pgm in here /au/test/csr/new/pgm? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your Subversion operations cannot cross the boundaries of the working copy, e.g., you cannot make stuff like:

```
svn copy /home/jimmy/work/main.c /home/zach/work
```

They can often combine, as needed, working copy locations and repository URLs. In the specific case of branching, I recommend you use a repository URL as target path, something like:

```
svn copy /au/test/csr/pgm https://example.com/path-to-repo/branches/feature-foo
```

You can then (if you wish) switch your working copy to the new branch (this is not necessary, it merely allows you to reuse a single working copy):

```
cd /au/test/csr/pgm
svn switch ^/branches/feature-foo
```

Or you can everything within the repository, as the example in the documentation you link:

```
svn copy http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/trunk \
         http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/branches/my-calc-branch \
         -m "Creating a private branch of /calc/trunk."
```

You can run `svn help copy` you get an overview of all the combinations:

```
copy (cp): Copy files and directories in a working copy or repository.
usage: copy SRC[@REV]... DST

  SRC and DST can each be either a working copy (WC) path or URL:
    WC  -> WC:   copy and schedule for addition (with history)
    WC  -> URL:  immediately commit a copy of WC to URL
    URL -> WC:   check out URL into WC, schedule for addition
    URL -> URL:  complete server-side copy;  used to branch and tag
  All the SRCs must be of the same type. If DST is an existing directory,
  the sources will be added as children of DST. When copying multiple
  sources, DST must be an existing directory.

  WARNING: For compatibility with previous versions of Subversion,
  copies performed using two working copy paths (WC -> WC) will not
  contact the repository.  As such, they may not, by default, be able
  to propagate merge tracking information from the source of the copy
```